# How to send follow up email after someone clicks on a specific link in the previous email in Journey Builder?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder

I'm working on a nurture journey for a client and I'm looking for a better solution to use the Engagement Split in real-time (similar to the real-time behavioural engagement for mobile apps) and send an email once the customer click on any of the email links.

Does anyone know if it's possible to send a follow-up e-mail directly after someone clicks on a specific link in the previous e-mail?

The scenario is that the client want to have an email send then a waiting time of 5 days but during this 5 days if the customer click on any of the email links they want a follow up email to be send within 1 day. At the moment I have 5 days waiting time > engagement check for clicks > follow up email but looks like they want this to work in real-time.

I can use multiple decision splits and use engagement split after every day during the 5 day period and check if the email has been clicked then follow up with the next email (if it is) or exit the customer (if it's not).

This will make the journey more complex and I was wondering if there is a way around to make this process more simple.

Thank you!

Comment: You can add a CloudPage that would open before the target link opens and on that CloudPage use a triggered send to immediately send an email once it’s opened. Then use a redirect function to open the target link. The whole thing would add additional few seconds of processing time once someone clicks on the link, but it should still be a good experience for your users and it would trigger the follow up email immediately. Click here for more on triggered sends: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2019/11/25/introduction-to-triggered-sends/

Comment: Thank you @zuzannamj this is really helpful and it's matching with my issue. Should help to resolve it. Much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: @zuzannamj I'm trying to make it work but I have issue with the CloudPage. I was using the code from the article as a base but when I created the CloudPage which will be used in the emails to redirect the customers and getting ''Error 500''.  Are you able to help with this?